# Implementing content for each tab item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I almost finished designing my vertical tab, but I got stuck. I'm having a hard time putting the contents for the appropriate menu items next to each other for example, if I click on home, I should see "Content for the home tab in a panel next to it in a  or container of some sort."

When I tried to put the contents of each of the tabs items, it places it at the bottom of the navigation menu. I couldn't figure out how to align the contents to the left side of the navigation menu. How can I show/align the contents of each menu item by clicking on one of the menu items?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         

 //----------Select the first tab and div by default
 
 $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').eq(0).addClass( "selected" );
 $('#cssmenu > div > ul').eq(0).css('display','block');


 //---------- This assigns an onclick event to each tab link("a" tag) and passes a parameter to the showHideTab() function
   
  $('#cssmenu > ul').click(function(e){
   
      if($(e.target).is("a")){
      
        /*Handle Tab Nav*/
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').removeClass( "selected");
        $(e.target).addClass( "selected");
        
        /*Handles Tab Content*/
        var clicked_index = $("a",this).index(e.target);
        $('#cssmenu > div > ul').css('display','none');
        $('#cssmenu > div > ul').eq(clicked_index).fadeIn();
        
      }
      
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
      
  });
  
  
});//end ready
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */

#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}


/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #141414;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 200px;
}

#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background-color: #141414;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 180%;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  border-right: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active a {
  background-color: #070707;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #070707;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c82b5;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c82b5;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #0fa1e0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #09638a;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#a'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#b'><span>Products</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#c'><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#d'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="a">
      a. Content for home tab in a panel next to it
    </div>
    <div id="b">
      b. Content for products tab in a panel next to it
    </div>
    <div id="c">
      c. Content for about tab in a panel next to it
    </div>
    <div id="d">
      d. Content for contact tab in a panel next to it
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: where is the javascript part?

Comment: I included the JavaScript, but it has errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple changes there, but here is the fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content-container div').hide()
    $('.content-container div').eq(0).show();
    
    $('#cssmenu a').click(function(e){
        /*Handle Tab Nav*/
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').removeClass( "selected");
        $(e.target).addClass( "selected");
        
        var index = $(this).parent('li').index();
        $('.content-container div').hide()
        $('.content-container div').eq(index).show();
    });
});//end ready
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.content-container {
  float: left;
  background: white;
}
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */

#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}


/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #141414;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu a {
  background-color: #141414;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 180%;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  border-right: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active a {
  background-color: #070707;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #070707;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c82b5;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c82b5;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #0fa1e0;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #09638a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#a'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#b'><span>Products</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#c'><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#d'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div id="a">
        a. Content for home tab in a panel next to it
      </div>
      <div id="b">
        b. Content for products tab in a panel next to it
      </div>
      <div id="c">
        c. Content for about tab in a panel next to it
      </div>
      <div id="d">
        d. Content for contact tab in a panel next to it
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

> You might need to change the css of the menu and the content to make it work exactly the way you want.